# Unclear about a tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

[Can I season cast iron *without* using an oven?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46131/can-i-season-cast-iron-without-using-an-oven)

I added the cast-iron tag, that seems clear enough. What about "seasoning"? Is that referring to the flavoring of food or the care of cookware?

Either way, the "seasoning" tag should have a summary. I'm happy to write it, but I want to know on which definition of the word to base the summary.

Answer (score 3):

From a quick look at the questions with the tag, [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning) has been used for both (not ideal), but [seasoning-pans](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning-pans) is on plenty of questions too. Seems fair to just maintain that split, write up [seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning) as flavoring not pans, and try to retag a bit!

Comment: Fair enough...I'll do it :)

Comment: I tried [tag:seasoning] first. I'm not sure that it worked as intended. Did I do that right? I mean for the "use [tag:seasoning-pans] for cookware" to show up if you hover over the tag, and the link to the relevant question to come up if you click for more info.

Comment: `seasoning-pans` has always been the tag for that particular type of seasoning; the usage of `seasoning` for that is incorrect. (This was decided waaaay back, during the public or maybe even private beta).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't mean to suggest there was any question - using `seasoning` for pans was in the minority.

Comment: My first tag wiki was approved and it looks how I intended, so I'll do a few more that have been bugging me. My next one will be [tag:seasoning-pans]. Thanks guys, I get it now. I'll retag all of the misstagged questions under *seasoning* and *seasoning-pans*, but I'll do it over time so as not to flood the board.